# What does "@main" mean in Xcode 12?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit, xcode12

> Xcode 12 includes support for using @main in place of @UIApplicationMain or @NSApplicationMain in UIKit- or AppKit-based apps. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-12-release-notes)

Newly created Xcode 12 project now using `@main` to indicate the application starting point.

1. What does it mean?
2. What does it do?
3. How the app start now?

Read a few blog posts that say that `@main` replaces `@UIApplicationMain` and in order to make it work a static `main` method needs to be defined. However, there is no `main` method in the `AppDelegate`, and the app launches with no issues.

**macOS project created in Xcode 12**

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {}

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {}
}
```

**iOS project created in Xcode 12**

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool { return true }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html#ID626?

Comment: but why there is no `main` function in AppDelegate?

Comment: first question you should ask yourself: why there is main function in AppDelegate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIApplicationMain first instantiates `UIApplication` and retains its instance to serve as the shared application instance (`UIApplication.shared`) and then instantiates the app delegate marked `@Main` as the application instance's delegate.  The `main` method exists as a [type method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/3656306-main).

Answer (score 1):

`@main` is attribute to indicate that this is the entry point of the app, and it’s no possible to have more than one structure.